# How to avoid old widgets failing/disappearing during major code rework?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have an app on the market which supports widgets.  I've made some heavy changes to the app, reworking a lot of the internals, replacing/renaming activities, etc.  Other changes include sourcing the widget configuration data from different shared preference keys, though I've written conversion code to handle the migration.  The app works as I wish it to, including the widgets, when installed from fresh.  However, I'm now testing upgrading from an old version of the app to a new one (via emulators).  I'm seeing some bizarre behaviour.  On one occasion the widget appeared OK on initial launch, but when clicked on tried to launch an old activity rather than the new one I've programmed.  So first question is, why didn't the widget update to the new code on app install?

The rest of my attempts at testing the upgrade have caused existing widgets to disappear entirely on a new version install.  What could be causing this?  Nothing of note appears in the log-cat logs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... replacing/renaming activities ...

There's your problem. If you rename an AppWidget receiver, it will disappear. The only solution is not to rename it.

Similar for an activity that can be pinned to the homescreen. If you rename the activity, the homescreen icon will disappear.

Read more about it here: [Android Developers Blog: Things That Cannot Change](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)

Comment: In my case I haven't renamed the AppWidget receiver, but have renamed the main/launcher activity.  I'll try un-factoring it.  Brilliant link by the way.  Thanks

Comment: UPDATE: Renamed main activity to old name and rejigged the manifest and lo!  It now migrates successfully from old to new.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You could also add an <activity-alias> to re-route old component references to your new activities.  This doesn't work for app widget providers but it will allow you to refactor activities.